# Why is this question not constructive: what SF features are subject to regulation?

Tags: discussion

[what SF features are subject to regulation?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/what-sf-features-are-subject-to-regulation)

> this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

How?

I am at a loss why this would be closed? Is it because it is not a coding question?

Answer (score 3):

I think that your example falls into the *extended discussion* realm. There so many government agencies world-wide that regulate data it would be near impossible to answer. If the question were restricted to something like, "Which Salesforce features are subject to regulation by the United States Securities Exchange Commission" (or other specific entity) then the narrower scope would help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the question falls in a grey zone and that possible answers may be very interesting. But, I gave a close vote because I think the question to be too unspecific, not scoped and therefor even in community context would be hard to answer to any extend.